# audio in and out by different channels

Tags: sound

My mic input is dead so I use external audio device (USB Genius GTALK) for microphone. For audio output I use the mainboard audio output. It works fine this way but when I reboot the audio output is set to the external Genius GTALK. Changing back audio output manually to line out it is fine again.
 How can I set it as default setting, boot this way eliminating the manual intervention?